# PXE server to boot ISO or other linux distro over network

Tags: networking, pxe

How do i setup my ubuntu desktop to act as a pxe server to boot ISO's across the LAN. And is it possible to run linux distros like linux mint, moblin etc so that boot at client would be faster.

I have some Intel Atom kits which can run windows 7 pretty fast.. but I want them to run customized linux which can show only browsers. So I thoght of making live CD image(iso) and boot them from network. Rather than spending money for harddrive for every clients which is not going to be used other than booting os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look into clonezilla http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-SE.php I'm sure there are other options available but you can use the drbl to auto start via pxe to just load a basic client on the machines.. Either to image the machines or to boot into a client for them to run.   There are a few thin clients you can look into also http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/linux_terminal_server# has a good rundown of some info on setting up and how well it runs